# Problems relate to directive in angular JS

Tags: angularjs

I am new to Angular Js and i have just done basic tags of angularjs,controller and when i started directive part i understood the concept but was unable to fetch data input written in template which is one of the directive property..Please guide me so that i can take one step further in AngularJS.

Thanks in Advance!!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div ng-app="appname" directive-name></div>
<script>

var app = angular.module("appname",[]);
app.directive("directiveName",function()
{
   return
   {
     template : "Hi i am template"
   };
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

<strike>There are many problems:</strike>

<strike>1. You should use `https` for cdn</strike>

<strike>2. You have to put `var app = angular.module("appname",[]);` before the `ng-app` tag</strike>

3. the return should be

   `return {   //the brace should be after return
            template : "Hi i am template"
          };`

because in modern browsers semicolons are not mandatory(they are added automatically), so `return` means returns nothing.
finally:

```
      <script>

    var app = angular.module("appname",[]);
    app.directive("directiveName",function()
    {
       return{
         template : "Hi i am template"
       };
    });
    </script>
```

Comment: I think your point 1 and 2 are incorrect and not relevant. Can you please give an explanation ?

Comment: well 1 is relevant when you use plnkr or jsfiddle which uses https. for 2, somehow I got 'appname' is not defined error :s but you are correct

Comment: The community is not meant for your issues in plunkr or jsfiddle.  Please don't put such assertive answer as there may be people who needs to be benefited and not misguided.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing wrong with your logic or Angular, it's because of JavaScript automatic semicolon insertion. Lines that do not end with a semicolon, but could be the end of a statement are automatically terminated. So, your return statement -

```
app.directive("directiveName",function()
{
   return  //automatic semicolon insertion here
   {
     template : "Hi i am template"
   };
});
```

Should be indeed -

```
app.directive("directiveName",function()
{
   return{
     template : "Hi i am template"
   };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your close:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="appname" ng-controller="MyController">
<h1>{{Header}}</h1>
<my-template></my-template>
<script>

var app = angular.module("appname",[]);
app.controller("MyController", function ($scope){
  $scope.Header = "My Directive";

});
app.directive("myTemplate",function() {
   return    {
     template : "<span>Hi i am template</span>",
     restrict: 'E',
   };
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

I've tested the above code and will render your directive.

Answer (score 0):

everything is allright, except the linebreak after the return.

```
 return {
     template : "Hi i am template"
  };
```